# How can I reduce the code used to create a reproducible dataframe using set.seed() and sample()?

Tags: r

I want to create a fairly large and reproducible dataset called `Activity` to pose a question here at StackOverFlow. My dataframe would consist of the variables:

1. `DateTime`: date and time with milliseconds and a data rate of 11 values per second, i.e. 11 rows per second.
2. `ID`: refers to the individual. I want to create a data set containing data for 3 individuals (`A`, `B` and `C`).
3. `x`: random data ranging from -1 to +1.
4. `y`: random data ranging from -1 to +1.
5. `z`: random data from -1 to +1.

I initially used this code:

```
set.seed(100)
fmt <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"

DateTime = seq(from=as.POSIXct("2017-08-05 14:03:55.300", format=fmt, tz="UTC"), by=1/11, length.out=67)
ID = rep("A", each=67)
x= sample(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.01), size = 67, replace = TRUE)
y= sample(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.01), size = 67, replace = TRUE)
z= sample(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.01), size = 67, replace = TRUE)
Activity1<- data.frame(DateTime,ID, x, y, z)

DateTime = seq(from=as.POSIXct("2017-08-05 16:18:12.100", format=fmt, tz="UTC"),by=1/11, length.out=67)
ID = rep("B", each=67)
x= sample(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.01), size = 67, replace = TRUE)
y= sample(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.01), size = 67, replace = TRUE)
z= sample(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.01), size = 67, replace = TRUE)
Activity2<- data.frame(DateTime,ID, x, y, z)

DateTime = seq(from=as.POSIXct("2017-08-05 20:34:31.540", format=fmt, tz="UTC"),by=1/11, length.out=67)
ID = rep("C", each=67)
x= sample(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.01), size = 67, replace = TRUE)
y= sample(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.01), size = 67, replace = TRUE)
z= sample(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.01), size = 67, replace = TRUE)
Activity3<- data.frame(DateTime,ID, x, y, z)
Activity<- rbind(Activity1,Activity2,Activity3)

head(Activity)
                   DateTime ID     x     y     z
1 2017-08-05 14:03:55.29999  A  0.01  0.82 -0.56
2 2017-08-05 14:03:55.39090  A  0.11  0.74  0.07
3 2017-08-05 14:03:55.48182  A  0.50  0.95 -0.64
4 2017-08-05 14:03:55.57273  A  0.97 -0.89  0.95
5 2017-08-05 14:03:55.66364  A -0.97  0.78 -0.01
6 2017-08-05 14:03:55.75454  A -0.46  0.20  1.00
```

How could I create this same dataframe using less code? I need to create a reproducible dataframe in another post in StackOverFlow and other users tell me that I should use less code to create my example.

Comment: Are they using different R versions? It was reported that changes to `sample` in R 3.6 made it not reproducible between versions https://community.rstudio.com/t/getting-different-results-with-set-seed/31624

Comment: That's possible!! And do you know how to simplify the code to create a dataframe as the oneI desired??

Comment: I am using the version `1.2.5033`. Can you check yours and tell me if you get the same dataframe than me?

Comment: *"I am using the version `1.2.5033`"*; that's highly probably the version of RStudio, not R; check the output of `sessionInfo()` for which version of R you are using

Comment: One can use the `RNGversion()` function to get newer versions of R to use an older version of the random number generator.  For example, `RNGversion("3.5.1")` tells R to use the 3.5.1 version of the random number generator.

Comment: I updated my R version and now I get the same result than other people, so the problem was my R version!! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different ways to achieve the same result. This is what I would do using my preferred tools:

```
library(data.table)
# define parameters to control the process
base_data <- fread("DateTime, ID, N
2017-08-05 14:03:55.300, A, 67
2017-08-05 16:18:12.100, B, 67
2017-08-05 20:34:31.540, C, 67")[
  , DateTime := lubridate::ymd_hms(DateTime)]
# expand sequences rowwise
Activity <- base_data[, .(DateTime = seq(from = DateTime, by = 1/11, length.out = N)), 
                      by = .(rn = seq(nrow(base_data)), ID)][
                        , rn := NULL][]
# create x, y, z columns by sampling
cols <- c("x", "y", "z")
set.seed(100)
Activity[,  (cols) := replicate(length(cols), round(runif(.N, -1, +1), 2), simplify = FALSE)]

Activity
```

> ```
>      ID            DateTime     x     y     z
>   1:  A 2017-08-05 14:03:55 -0.38  0.91 -0.28
>   2:  A 2017-08-05 14:03:55 -0.48  0.83 -0.12
>   3:  A 2017-08-05 14:03:55  0.10  0.65  0.61
>   4:  A 2017-08-05 14:03:55 -0.89 -0.36  0.04
>   5:  A 2017-08-05 14:03:55 -0.06  0.76  0.39
>  ---                                         
> 197:  C 2017-08-05 20:34:37 -0.76 -0.52 -0.81
> 198:  C 2017-08-05 20:34:37  0.20  0.44 -0.59
> 199:  C 2017-08-05 20:34:37 -0.76 -0.41 -0.94
> 200:  C 2017-08-05 20:34:37  0.58  0.02  0.16
> 201:  C 2017-08-05 20:34:37 -0.26 -0.44 -0.69
> ```

Fractions of second are not printed by default but the 1/11 second increment can be verified by

```
head(diff(Activity$DateTime))
```

> ```
> Time differences in secs
> [1] 0.09090900 0.09090924 0.09090900 0.09090900 0.09090924 0.09090900
> ```

As the OP has *not* requested to reproduce his results exactly with the given seed value I have replaced

```
sample(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.01), size = 67, replace = TRUE)
```

by

```
round(runif(.N, -1, +1), 2)
```

In case `sample()` is a requirement, the `seq()` part can be skipped by

```
sample((-100:100)/100, .N, replace = TRUE)
```

Using `data.table` *chaining* the code can be written even more concisely as

```
library(data.table)
cols <- c("x", "y", "z")
set.seed(100)
Activity <- fread("DateTime, ID, N
2017-08-05 14:03:55.300, A, 67
2017-08-05 16:18:12.100, B, 67
2017-08-05 20:34:31.540, C, 67")[
  , DateTime := lubridate::ymd_hms(DateTime)][
    , .(DateTime = seq(from = DateTime, by = 1/11, length.out = N)), 
    by = .(rn = seq(nrow(base_data)), ID)][
      ,  (cols) := replicate(length(cols), round(runif(.N, -1, +1), 2), simplify = FALSE)][
        , rn := NULL][]
```

Comment: Thanks @Uwe, It looks awesome!! One doubt, what are `cyl`,  `disp` and `wt`? You show them after the first code option.

Comment: @Dekike This was just a mishap. I have corrected my answer. (Apparently, I haven't had cleaned up my workspace properly...)